# How to check if data table has empty rows?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am writing function that filters out some random data from a data table `random` according to an id value ,but I want it first to check if there is actual data rows in the data table first. I ended up writing an if statement and using `is.null` but its still for the condition but its not working and ends up accessing the else statement and then giving me an error. 
The code is posted below, please help me

```
new.filterID <- function(DataTable,id) {
  if(DataTable == is.null){
    return(print("No Data Available: ",id))
  } else { filtered <- subset(DataTable, ID == id)
    return(aggregate(Value ~ YEAR_WW, filtered, mean))
  }
}
filteredData <- new.filterID(random, 213)
```

The error I get when I run this is

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate
```

Also below the empty data table `random`

```
Value   YEAR_WW
```

Comment: Use `if(nrow(DataTable) == 0)`. The object still exists, even if it doesn't contain any data.

Comment: Thanks it worked @lmo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use [nrow](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/nrow.html) if you just want to check if the number of lines is zero:

```
new.filterID <- function(DataTable,id) {
  if(nrow(DataTable) == 0){
   return(print("No Data Available: ",id))
  } else { 
   filtered <- subset(DataTable, ID == id)
   return(aggregate(Value ~ YEAR_WW, filtered, mean))
  }
}
filteredData <- new.filterID(random, 213)
```

However, if you want to check if data.table is null you can check if there is some column on it:

```
new.filterID <- function(DataTable,id) {
  if(nrow(DataTable) == 0 & length(names(DataTable)) == 0){
   return(print("No Data Available: ",id))
  } else { 
   filtered <- subset(DataTable, ID == id)
   return(aggregate(Value ~ YEAR_WW, filtered, mean))
  }
}
filteredData <- new.filterID(random, 213)
```

Data table has not a method to check if it is null, yet.